# GLSurfaceView hiding the ImageView undesired

Tags: android, opengl-es

There is an ImageView and a GLSurfaceView setup with 'match_parent' parameters on the screen.  The ImageView gets populated quickly and shows up on the screen.  Then, the GLSurfaceView gets populated on top of it with modifications to the image.  So far so good.

However, these views also live inside of a ViewPager with images to the left and right of them.  Before introducing the OpenGL Surface View on top of the ImageView, the views would transition out to the left and right as expected.  But after introducing the GLSurfaceView on top of it, as soon as the user starts to swipe their fingers to move to the next image, the SurfaceView becomes transparent causing the image to disappear.  It even forces the image below it to disappear in the ImageView.  Showing the background of the parent view.

I am unclear on how to approach this issue.  It would be nice if the texture slid out to the side just like the ImageView or even be transparent but leave the ImageView behind it visible would be fine.

Even GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOSLY doesn't keep the texture around during the transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that the reason that I cannot get the effect that I am trying to achieve is because the GLSurfaceView is always placed behind other views causing transparency on the foreground views.  Thus, the GLSurfaceView would have priority over being drawn.  In order to achieve the effect that I would want, I probably need to be sure to use View.setVisibility( ) for invisible when swiping and set it back to visible after the ViewPager settles.  That is the current conclusion that I have come across after seeing a couple other links as a by-product of different research.

[z-order for GLSurfaceViews](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/android-developers/fQihJKLki7M/nz4QWV8eyxQJ)

[scrolling in GLSurfaceViews](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/android-developers/zkdnM0G225I/tt_FJGyOkB4J)

It doesn't seem as though the GLSurfaceView class really performs as similar to a view as I had been originally expecting.  So a little extra care will need to be taken in order to progress further to keep the ImageView visible transitioning between images in the ViewPager.

Within a viewPager I managed to accomplish something along the lines of the following code.  This is still in a rough state of course since it was in the middle of testing, but it accomplishes what I am looking for.  Which is for a texture to start loading when we begin to settle on an image, and then disappear revealing the original image below it once the user begins to leave the image.  And this seems to work without tearing or flickers which is how I would expect for it to behave.

```
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
{
    switch(state)
    {
        case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING:
            Log.i("photoViewer:","dragging ViewPager");
            if(photoSurfaceView_ != null  && photoViewFrameLayout != null)
            {
                photoSurfaceView_.setAlpha(0);
                photoSurfaceView_.invalidate();
            }
            break;
        case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
            photoSurfaceView_.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            photoSurfaceView_.setAlpha(1);
            Log.i("photoViewer:","idle ViewPager");
            break;
        case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING:
            int childCount = photoViewFrameLayout.getChildCount();
            if(childCount >= 2)
            {
                photoViewFrameLayout.removeViews(1, childCount-1);
            }
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Looper.prepare();
                    final Bitmap openGlBitmap = BitmapFactoryUtils.resizeAsNecessaryForOpenGLtexture(photoPaths[photoViewPager_.getCurrentItem()], new BitmapFactory.Options());
                    Rect bounds = BitmapFactoryUtils.calculateBoundsForBitmap(activityContext, openGlBitmap);
                    int scaledHeight = bounds.height();
                    int scaledWidth = bounds.width();
                    photoSurfaceView_ = new PhotoViewSurfaceView(activityContext, openGlBitmap);
                    photoSurfaceView_.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, Gravity.CENTER));
                    photoSurfaceView_.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    photoSurfaceView_.setAlpha(0);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            photoViewFrameLayout.addView(photoSurfaceView_);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();

            Log.i("photoViewer:","settling ViewPager");
            break;
    }
```

***Edit:***  As requested I wanted to provide some additional input as to how to resize the texture for an OpenGL `SurfaceView` that will use a `Bitmap` for input.

The following is a quick snippet of some of the code available for the first step in the process in checking against whether or not the texture size of the current Bitmap will fit within a single texture.  If you want to tile the texture to keep the image larger, then this gets more complicated and this was not what was needed for my resolution.

The texture size can be retrieved with the following code:

```
private void assignTextureSize()
{
    /* The maximum texture size can be found within the OpenGL context and then shared amongst other applications. */
    int[] maxTextureSize = new int[1];

    GLES20.glGetIntegerv(GLES20.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxTextureSize, 0);

    maxTextureSize = maxTextureSize[0];
}
```

but only from within the `Renderer` class and for my case I waited until within the onDrawFrame of the Texture to do the assignment; before a Bitmap has been assigned to it.

Then, the goal of the `Bitmap` being loaded for me was to simply load what I could without running out of memory.  For this, I simply modified the `Options` of the Bitmap that I was about to load and try and load it within a try catch block.  If it ran out of memory, I would try it again, but with a smaller footprint.

```
try
{
    final int sizeFactors[] = { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 };

    if (new File(bitmapFilePath).exists())
    {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeFactors.length; ++i)
        {
            try
            {
                options.inSampleSize = sizeFactors[i];
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bitmapFilePath, options);

                if(bmp.getHeight() > maximumTextureSize ||
                       bmp.getWidth() > maximumTextureSize)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                /*
                 * @category Check against EXIF data if the image needs to be rotated or not for viewing.
                 */
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix ();
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(bitmapFilePath); 
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt (ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1); 
                switch(orientation) 
                { 
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                        break; 
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90: 
                        matrix.postRotate (90); 
                        break; 
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180: 
                        matrix.postRotate (180);
                        break; 
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        matrix.postRotate (270); 
                        break; 
                    default: 
                } 

                bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap (bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth (), bmp.getHeight (), matrix, true);

                return bmp;
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError outOfMemory)
            {
                //Do nothing, it will return when one that doesn't run out of memory is loaded.  Or you could do additional checking to bail if needed, etc.
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Not enough memory for loading image");
    }
} catch (Exception exception)
{
    Log.e("CustomLogTag", "Exception for loading the image that was selected for extraction.");
}
```

There are many ways to accomplish this, but this is one approach to take and I wanted to add clarity and additional information to this previous post as requested since it did not contain as much information on my accepted answer as I would have like either.

Comment: @alexlodoss The above code that I had supplied ended up working for me.  I had a low resolution photograph in an `ImageView` behind the `SurfaceView`.  So, when the `ViewPager` is being interacted with, the low-resolution `Bitmap` is shown and when it settles I bring the `SurfaceView` back into visibility.

Comment: Tell me please, when you get class BitmapFactoryUtils? I don't noticed it at first time...

Comment: @alexlodoss I just updated my answer to cover bitmap resizing that was used for this project in order to show a more complete description of what was used for the ViewPager.